# GetConstructor returning nothing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reflection, getconstructor

I have two different GetConstructors(), one is returning what it should be returning the other however is returning nothing.

ItemName is **BSRPTReportPerformanceSubcontractorRating**

The first one which is returning what it properly should is:

```
Shared Function Invoke(ByVal Page As FXWBPage, ByVal ItemName As String, ByVal intFolderID As Integer, ByVal strItemID As String, ByVal strDummy As String) As BSRPTPrint
        Dim objPrint As BSRPTPrint

    Dim objConstructor As System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo
    Dim objType As Type
    Dim strType As String = "FXWB.BSRPT" & ItemName
    Dim types() As Type = {GetType(FXWBPage), GetType(Integer), GetType(String)}
    Dim args() As Object = {Page, intFolderID, strItemID}

    Try
        Try
            objType = Type.GetType(strType, True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Cannot reflect type """ & strType & """. Check Request parameter ""PrintItem"", it must take the name of correspondig BSRPT class without BSRPT prefix", ex)
        End Try

        objConstructor = objType.GetConstructor(types)

        If objConstructor Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Cannot invoke type """ & objType.ToString() & """. Check constructor parameter, it must be of FXWBPage type and not passed by ref.")
        End If

        Try
            objPrint = objConstructor.Invoke(args)
        Catch exep As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Cannot load report """ & strType & """. Error: " & exep.Message)
        End Try

        Try
            objPrint.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error occured on data binding level. Report """ & strType & """.", ex)
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw ex

    End Try


    Return objPrint
End Function
```

The second which is returning Nothing is:

```
Shared Function Invoke(ByVal Page As FXWBPage, ByVal ItemName As String, ByVal intFolderID As Integer, ByVal intProjectID As Integer, ByVal strDummy As String, ByVal intSubcontractorID As Integer) As BSRPTPrint
    Dim objPrint As BSRPTPrint


    Dim objConstructor As System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo
    Dim objType As Type
    Dim strType As String = "FXWB.BSRPT" & ItemName
    Dim types() As Type = {GetType(FXWBPage), GetType(Integer), GetType(Integer), GetType(String), GetType(Integer)}
    Dim args() As Object = {Page, intFolderID, intProjectID, intSubcontractorID}

    Try
        Try
            objType = Type.GetType(strType, True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Cannot reflect type """ & strType & """. Check Request parameter ""PrintItem"", it must take the name of correspondig BSRPT class without BSRPT prefix", ex)
        End Try

        objConstructor = objType.GetConstructor(types)

        If objConstructor Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Cannot invoke type """ & objType.ToString() & """. Check constructor parameter, it must be of FXWBPage type and not passed by ref.")
        End If

        Try
            objPrint = objConstructor.Invoke(args)
        Catch exep As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Cannot load report """ & strType & """. Error: " & exep.Message)
        End Try

        Try
            objPrint.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error occured on data binding level. Report """ & strType & """.", ex)
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw ex

    End Try


    Return objPrint
End Function
```

Can anyone help me understand why the first one is working and the second one is returning nothing.

Comment: What type is objType first of all? I assume your second GetConstructor is returning Nothing just because your objType class doesn't have relevant constructor...

Comment: apologies I added the line of code for what objType is

Comment: Still that's not what I was asking about :) I do understand it's of type Type. But what _class_ are you trying to get constructor for?

Comment: the function these are contained in are BSRPTPrint, both functions that include these are the exact same there is no difference in any code except for the amount of array items within types()

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding exactly what you are asking

Comment: I added more code to maybe help with the question

Comment: @mattgcon: what @Sergey Kudriavtsev wanted to know is: does your class `"FXWB.BSRPT" & ItemName` has a constructor with parameters(in this order) : `FXWBPage, Integer, Integer, String, Integer`?

Comment: Actually it is a custom class within the application that was created before I came on board. I think I figured out what he was asking when I looked at his questino and looked at the code.

Comment: @Sergey: thank you for helping guide me to the answer, it was what you were referring to I just had to dive deeper. The ItemName (FXWBPage page) did not have the correct amount of variables in the constructor. Create an answer to what you suggested so that I can mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments:

I see from your updated code that "FXWB.BSRPT" & ItemName is not your class but rather some third-party component, right? Then you should consult docs on this component or contact its author for getting information why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have another argument in args(), have you verified that the types of the variables you have there match up, and there is actually a constructor which takes those 4 args?